# Convert markdown to readme with bootsrap 3

Tags: bootstrap-4, markdown, readme

I want to Convert my readme markdown to a .html file. The html file must contain a bootstrap css header. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with Error handling and variable inputs + Bootsrap 3 integration.

```
#! How to use: python3 md2html.py input.md output.html
import markdown
import sys

md_in_file = sys.argv[1]
html_out_file = sys.argv[2]

bootstrap_header = '<title>PPPT2HTML</title> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>'

try:
    with open(md_in_file, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
        html = markdown.markdown(text)
        
        print("✔️ MarkDown file found")

    with open(html_out_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(bootstrap_header + html)
        
        print("✔️ HTML file created")

except NameError:
    print("❌ ERR0R: File not found")

except:
    print("❌ ERR0R: general ERR0R")
```

USE:

```
python3 md2html.py input.md output.html
```